# Insert row with data into excel sheet from another sheet dynamically

Tags: vba, excel

I have two different excel sheet first sheet contain some country list and second sheet is blank. There is a dropdown column with every country which contain 'Yes' 'No'. When I select yes I want that, the selected country row will automatically add to second sheet with all data. When I select more country they will dynamically insert/add to second sheet with maintaining country order in the first sheet.
[image: Excel dynamic row insert] These can be done with macro but I want to do this with formula.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$C$7,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$D$1:$D$7="Yes",ROW(Sheet1!$D$1:$D$7),1E+99),ROW($A1)),COLUMN(A$1)),"")`

Input formula in *Cell A2* of **Sheet2** and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
Then copy to remaining cells. Adjust the addresses in the formula to suit. HTH

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in Sheet1, no of country is dynamic so I do not know exact no. because It will input by my client.

Comment: @MdRiadHossain You can use a ***[Dynamic Named Range](http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html)*** and then use that in the formula instead.